# O(3^n) vs O(n ^ (log_3 n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

This is a small brain teaser I've picked up that I'm finding difficulty analysing. How would O(3^n) vs O(n ^ (log_3 n)) compare?

Would this be something like logarithmic functions being O of each other due to being able to change base?

Comment: Why don't you load up Excel/LibreOffice Calc/whatever and plot the numbers? I'm not really sure what exactly the question is getting at.

Comment: @KenY-N I was wondering if there might be a general method to tackle this pattern of problem if one might not necessarily have access to a graph plotter

Comment: Perhaps this might be better asked at [mathematics.se] then?

Comment: @KenY-N Possibly. But then again I think one could make an equal argument that it places better here since big O notation is more core to Computer Science domains.

Comment: @dk123 surely then it would belong on [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @NickA Great point, I didn't even know that one existed. Would you consider this more fitting there? I'm not sure how this type of question would be sorted.

Comment: @dk123 Honestly couldn't say, there are plenty BigO questions on CS, SO and Mathematics, it may also be on topic on [Computation Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), which is most suitable I have no idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have uploaded the proof. But sorry for my writing. Because it is not so good.
But i tried my best. i used the mathematical induction for the proof.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can prove it mathematically but for the simplicity i make a graph.
The `O(n ^ (log_3 n))`  , `O(n ^ (log 3n))` are better than `O(3^n)` 
You can see in the image that:

Good to bad ranking

1. Blue
2. Green
3. Red

[image]

Comment: +1 for great presentation and detail. Would you happen to be able to present the mathematical proof as well?

Comment: wait is am sending the proof